# JPA Hibernate in clause not working in postgres

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

The below JPA query works in Oracle but not in PostGres

```
@Query("select new com.mypackage.UserInfo(m.usrmstId, m.usrName) 
from UsrMst m where m.usrName in :names ")
public List<UserInfo> getUserByNames(@Param("names")List<String> names);
```

I have verified the values in the list and it has the right values.
But the generated query has NULL

```
select usrmst0_.usrmst_id as col_0_0_, usrmst0_.usr_name as col_1_0_from usr_mst usrmst0_ where
(usrmst0_.usr_name in (NULL)) limit 2147483647  {executed in 8 msec}
```

We are using hibernate and the same code works fine in Oracle but the collection passed to the IN clause becomes NULL for PostGres

In case if anybody has faced this issue , please share your thoughts.

Comment: That looks strange. I'm using EclipseLink with Postgresql, and we have several `IN` queries, including `NOT IN` using both sub-selects and Sets of String as the target. I find it hard to think it is a bug in Hibernate, as they would surely have a test for something this trivial.

Comment: I agree. Will debug this again to find the root cause.